# How to return in anonymous function/function literal?

Tags: scala

I'm not sure how to use the `return` keyword in an anonymous function (or perhaps I should solve my problem in a different way?).

The way it is right now, the `return` actually refers to the enclosing function.

```
()=>{
  if (someMethodThatReturnsBoolean()) return true
  // otherwise do stuff here
}:Boolean
```

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to. Scala's `return` keyword _always_ and _only_ returns from top-level methods (at the level of a class, whether that class is named or not or whether it is nested or not). Hence `return` in a function literal _or_ a nested method is rarely useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not ?

```
() =>
  someMethodThatReturnsBoolean() || {
    //do stuff here that eventually returns a boolean
  }
```

Or, if you don't like to produce side effects with the `||` operator you can just use plain if:

```
() =>
  if (someMethodThatReturnsBoolean())
    true
  else {
    //do something here that returns boolean eventually
  }
```

`if` is just an expression in Scala and you should organize your code in an expression-like fashion and avoid `return` as much as possible.

Answer (score 4):

> The way it is right now, the return actually refers to the enclosing function.

This is how it is supposed to be. You cannot use `return` for returning from an anonymous function. You'll have to rewrite your code to avoid the `return` statement, as in:

```
()=>{
  if (someMethodThatReturnsBoolean()) true
  else {
    // otherwise do stuff here
  }
}:Boolean
```